# How to use GRUB2 to boot system rescue CD iso saved on unmounted partation at hard drive?

Tags: 12.04, boot, 12.10, dual-boot, grub2

I want to make a helper partition which may include a lot of `rescue ISO` files like 'Hiern's Boot', 'System Rescue', any live CD and Others.

I started to make a partition by using the following command:

> $ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

---

I used `fdisk` command parameters (or sub commands ) to make a partition `/dev/sdb6` [ extended partition ]

---

Then I made a mount point by using the following commands:

> $ sudo mkdir /mnt/Rescue
>
> $ sudo mount /dev/sdb6 /mnt/Rescue
>
> $ sudo chmod +rwx /mnt/Rescue

I then made a menu entry at **`/etc/grub.d/40_custom`** file with the following entries

> menuentry "Ubuntu-12.04-ISO" {
>
> > ```
> > set isofile="/mnt/ubu12-04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i368.iso"
> >
> > loopback loop (hd0,6)$isofile
> >
> > linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile 
> > noprompt noeject
> >
> > initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz }
> > ```

---

after all this I restarted my computer and found just the following entry: "Ubuntu-12.04-ISO " in the grub menu but it doesn't work. 
What did I do wrong?

Note: 
I am using 2 hard disks 1st one with /dev/sda and the 2nd with /dev/sdb

---

How can I make Boot for SystemRescueCD.iso , Heirn's Boot.iso and Ubuntu-12.04.iso ?

Comment: Did you use `sudo update-grub2` or `sudo update-grub` (depending on what you use) after all these steps?

Comment: yes I made update-grub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you had previously mounted this partition in /mnt doesn't matter and grub doesn't have any idea about that.  The file name within that partition is just /ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso, so you just need to drop the /mnt prefix.

Comment: Also is grub in sda or sdb. Boot drive with grub is always hd0, and then the other drive will be hd1.  So it may depend on which drive you boot from which is correct hdo or hd1.

Comment: I made what you said but nothing changed

Comment: @adam, you will have to be more specific that "doesn't work" then.  What errors does it give?

Comment: I just did what you said , but i changed 2 things

Comment: I just did what you said , but I changed 2 things , 1st one I put the following set isofile="/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i368.iso" , 2nd I put the following linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile 
noprompt noeject , now every thing is going all write and the iso file start just fine , thank you so much oldfred and psusi

Comment: psusi : update your answer with those tips , thank you again